# Identify repeating raws (loans) in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, rank

I have a table like this:

```
Client  Branch  Amount  Date
1        2      1500    1.1.14
1        2      1400    3.1.14
1        3      1500    1.1.14
1        4      300     7.1.14
1        5      1500    1.1.14
------------------------------
2        2      300     1.1.14
2        2      300     1.1.14
2        5      300     1.1.14
2        3      400     4.1.14
------------------------------           
3        2      300     1.1.14
3        2      300     1.1.14
3        5      300     1.1.14
3        5      300     1.1.14
3        3      400     4.1.14
4        2      300     1.1.14  
4        2      300     1.1.14 
4        5      300     1.1.14 
4        5      300     1.1.14  
4        5      300     1.1.14
```

And my desired output should be like this:

```
   Client   Branch  Amount  Date   Ind  Loan_Distinct_Num
    1        2      1500    1.1.14  0         1
    1        2      1400    3.1.14  0         2 
    1        3      1500    1.1.14  1         1
    1        4      300     7.1.14  0         3
    1        5      1500    1.1.14  1         1
    -------------------------------------------------
    2        2      300     1.1.14  0         1
    2        2      300     1.1.14  0         2
    2        5      300     1.1.14  1         2
    2        3      400     4.1.14  0         3
    --------------------------------------------------           
    3        2      300     1.1.14  0         1
    3        2      300     1.1.14  0         2 
    3        5      300     1.1.14  1         1
    3        5      300     1.1.14  1         2
    3        3      400     4.1.14  0         3
    ------------------------------------------------     
    4        2      300     1.1.14  0         1
    4        2      300     1.1.14  0         2
    4        5      300     1.1.14  1         1
    4        5      300     1.1.14  1         2
    4        5      300     1.1.14  0         3
```

So what am I trying to do? (Comment: Those records are just a sample data)

Well, those are the rules:
A client has moved from one branch to another in the same bank. The problem is that the branches were writing the data for him several times. I want to identify loans that are repeating. Two steps needed:

Step1 :
Assumption : Same_Amount + Same_Date + **Diffrent** Date  ---> Ind = 1 on the records that are **after** the first raw.

**How Ind field works?**

For example:
In the partition for client = 1 the amount 1500 is reapting 3 times for same date and diffrent branches but only the two last records for this details will get a "1" value for Ind, the first will get Ind = 0 because it is not a repeting loan, it is the first time that a record with this amount and date appears in the data.

In case like client = 2 there were two records for branch = 2 and only one for branch = 5 so in this case I will assum that the last record for the branch = 2 was being repeted.

In case like client = 3 there were two records in branch = 2 and two records for branch = 5 so in this case i will assume that both of the loans from branch 2 was repeted.

In Case client = 4, well it will be the same like client 3 but there was another record but I will consider it a new one because I have no extra past loan to communicate with her.

Step 2: I want to create my own distinct loan number for each client

Any help on how to **approach** for solving this nor simple problem?

comment : sql-server 2008.

Comment: Row_Number is good for case for client  = 1 . What about client = 2,3,4?

Comment: Are these records sequential by create time? For client 1, how do you know 1 / 2 / 1500 / 1.1.14 happened before 1 / 3 / 1500 / 1.1.14 or 1 / 5 / 1500 / 1.1.14?

Comment: Yes. Assume that the data is ordered correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer if ind should only be 1 if exists a previous record with a different branch # (see row 7). Also, uses dense_rank to group loans by amount/date in loan_distinct_num. The logic seems more complex for that column - if this is a one-time fix, I might use a cursor to loop through the table and apply some more complex logic to populate that one column, rather than try to calculate it in a query.

```
-- sample data
declare @data table (ID int identity(1,1), Client int, Branch int, Amount int, [Date] date);
insert into @data values
(1,2,  1500,'2014-01-01'),
(1,2,  1400,'2014-03-01'),
(1,3,  1500,'2014-01-01'),
(1,4,  300,'2014-07-01'),
(1,5,  1500,'2014-01-01'),
(2,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(2,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(2,5,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(2,3,  400,'2014-04-01'),
(3,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(3,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(3,5,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(3,5,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(3,3,  400,'2014-04-01'),
(4,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(4,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(4,5,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(4,5,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(4,5,  300,'2014-01-01');

-- query
select client, branch, amount, date, 
    case when exists (select * from @data t2 where client = tbl.client and branch <> tbl.branch and amount = tbl.amount and date = tbl.date and id < tbl.id) then 1 else 0 end as ind,
    DENSE_RANK() over (partition by client order by date, amount asc) as loan_disinct_num
from @data tbl
order by id;
```

Comment: Thank you. Any way to this without dense_rank?
 becuase I am using sqldf (sqllite).

Comment: `select client, branch, amount, date,
 (select count(*) from 
   (
    select distinct amount, date 
    from @data 
    where client = tbl.Client and (date < tbl.Date or (date = tbl.date and amount < tbl.Amount))
   )sq
 ) + 1 as dense_rank_different_approach
from @data tbl
order by id;` - this should be the equivalent of dense_rank using count and distinct

Answer (score 1):

First - set up your data into a table. I've added an identity column ID, so we have something to order by - you specified in a comment that your data was in a specific order.

```
declare @data table (ID int identity(1,1), Client int, Branch int, Amount int, [Date] date);
insert into @data values
(1,2,  1500,'2014-01-01'),
(1,2,  1400,'2014-03-01'),
(1,3,  1500,'2014-01-01'),
(1,4,  300,'2014-07-01'),
(1,5,  1500,'2014-01-01'),
(2,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(2,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(2,5,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(2,3,  400,'2014-04-01'),
(3,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(3,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(3,5,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(3,5,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(3,3,  400,'2014-04-01'),
(4,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(4,2,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(4,5,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(4,5,  300,'2014-01-01'),
(4,5,  300,'2014-01-01');
```

Here is where we do the query:

```
--In the first cte, we take all the data, and partition it up into individual loans (partition by Client, Amount, Date).
with cte1 as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Client, Amount, Date order by ID) as rowno from @data
), cte2 as (
    --in this cte, we get a list of distinct loans. We will use another rownumber in a bit to find our Loan_Distinct_Num
    select distinct Client, Amount, [Date] from @data
)
select cte1.Client, cte1.Branch, cte1.Amount, cte1.[Date]
      -- If rowno = 1, it's the first instance of that combination
    , case when rowno = 1 then 0 else 1 end as ind
    , b.Loan_Distinct_Num
 from cte1
 left join (select cte2.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by Client order by [Date]) as Loan_Distinct_Num
             -- This is where our distinct loan number comes from
              from cte2 
              ) as b
              on b.Client = cte1.Client and b.Amount = cte1.Amount and b.[Date] = cte1.[Date]
 order by ID
```

Comment: Is there any way to make the process run more fast? I'm trying running it on 2.5 million clients. 1 day has past and the proccess is still running.

Comment: Put an index on the table.